# VBA Copy Range and Paste to Another Sheet if Condition is Met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a novice when it comes to VBA, hence, appreciate your help on this.

My source sheet1 has columns A to V wherein my conditions are in column U.

What I'm trying to do is to copy and paste the data from row A2 and from columns A to P only if under column U, the text "Manual" is found. But below code is not working as everything is being copied over to Sheet2 and not just the rows that contain the text "Manual". Can you please check what is wrong with the below?

Also, if I'll add another `If` condition to the below code, in which I want to copy and paste rows from columns A to P only that has the text "Auto" to sheet 3, how can I modify the below code?

Many thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Paste Data").Select

LR = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    If Sheets("Paste Data").Cells(i, 21).Value = "Manual" Then
        Sheets("Paste Data").Range("A2:P" & LR).Rows(i).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Columns("A:P").AutoFit
    End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Paste Data").Activate
Sheets("Paste Data").Cells(1.1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: So you're looking in Sheet "Paste Data" but then copy from Sheet "Data"? Could use AutoFilter and copy the results from it.

Comment: Sorry, just missed the "Paste" text. Updated now.

Comment: Have a look at [vBasic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75316059/19353309) about using AutoFilter, you have the column number/last row already found out so shouldn't be an issue. Also, try to [avoid using Select/Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, try to avoid using `Select`, `Activate` and `ActiveSheet`.

The modified code below will copy columns "A:P" only if "<anual" is found in column U of each row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With Sheets("Paste Data")

    LR = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    For i = 2 To LR
        If .Range("U" & i).Value = "Manual" Then
            .Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)
        End If
    Next i
    
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False    

End Sub
```

*Note*: if you only need to copy the values without the cell's formatting, a quicker way will be:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Value
```

Comment: It worked, added code 'Sheets("Manual").Range("C1:C" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete' to delete the blank rows (non-Manual) Just want to understand please the above code when copyiing the values only please. If it's not too much, can you please give explain it? Many thanks Shai.

Comment: @kimini not sure if you are asking about the syntax of my answer? or another question not in your post?

Comment: Just the syntax please when when copying  both for with and without the formatting. Thank you.

Comment: @kimini `.Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)` is with formatting, and `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Value` is without formatting

Answer (score 0):

One more answer to that question.

As usual, there are multiple ways of doing what you ask: loop & read/write cell values, convert data to arrays and loop arrays (faster execution but longer coding), use AutoFilter per @[Notus_Panda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19353309/notus-panda) advice (the data need to be properly designed), or... copy the entire sheet and remove non-Manual records.

```
Sub FilterManual()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim oRng As Range, LR As Long
    
    ' define source sheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paste Data")


    ' copy it
    wsSource.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    wsTarget.Name = "Filtered"
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    ' detect range
    With wsTarget
        LR = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
        Set oRng = .Range("A1:U" & LR)
    End With

    ' filter out non-Manual entries
    oRng.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="<>Manual"
    
    ' delete them
    Rows("2:" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    ' reset filters
    On Error Resume Next
    wsTarget.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

The code above has several things to keep in mind:

- some sheets in your workbook may be hidden *and* located in the end. You need to unhide them or read carefully this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692274/copy-sheet-and-get-resulting-sheet-object) regarding the issue
- sheet name "Filtered" may already exist - use another unique name
- there can be no entries with "Manual" cells - the sheet will be empty
- dealing with large tables (millions of records) alongside with dozens of "heavy" sheets may require another approach since it may slow down execution or hang Excel.

---

Here is a source table and output after applying the macro:
[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I'll try this also.